# deploying to 1053 catalog help pls

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

hi i want to deploy to my 1053 catalog in 15 folder and not in 1033 how should i do then?
How could i change my TemplateFile Location to folder 1053 and not 1033?
Right not my url is 
Which is the enligsh folder in hive, i want for 1053....

I also have the problem i have created a site definition when choosing my template to create a site i get this error:
Failed to instantiate file "v4.master" from module "DefaultMasterPage": Source path "v4.master" not found.

Dont now why? my folders name are same ?

UPDATE
I have created a site definition in vs.

my temp_customsitedefinition.xml
[image]

my default.aspx
 [image]

my onet.xml[image]

All my files have deployment type Template file

Comment: Hej, can you give some more information about what your solution is structured and how you deploy it?

Comment: @Robban1980 i have updated

Answer (score 0):

MSDN describes how to create localized site definitions on this page [How to: Create Localized Versions of Custom Site Definitions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg603694(v=office.14).aspx) and here is the link to the previous article this one build on [enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454677(office.14).aspx)

In the first article describes step by step on how to create localized versions of custom site collection templates. How to create the folder in you visual studio project and where to set the LCID, so they are deployed to the correct folders. And the second link, describes what you should have already done based on your first question. The prerequisites for the steps below is that you already have a Custom Site collection definition project in VS.

1. Right-click the project name in Solution Explorer (not the Site Definition node), point to Add, and then select SharePoint Mapped Folder.
2. In the Add SharePoint Mapped Folder dialog box, navigate to TEMPLATE\LCID\XML, where LCID is the numeric identifier of the first language for which you want to provide a localized version of the site definition, and then click OK. An XML folder is created in your project.
3. Right-click the XML folder, point to Add, and then select New Item.
4. Click Visual C# or Visual Basic in the Installed Templates panel, and then select XML file.
5. Give the file the same name as you gave the custom webtemp*.xml file in the earlier topic, except that you should add the LCID to the file name just before the "."; for example, WebTemp_RESEARCH_3082.xml.
6. Click Add. Adding the file to the mapped folder in this manner automatically configures the package manifest to deploy the file to %ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LCID\XML, where LCID is the numeric identifier of the language.
7. Replace the contents of the new webtemp*_LCID.xml file with the contents of the original custom webtemp*.xml file that you created earlier.
8. Replace the values of the Title, Description, and DisplayCategory attributes in all the Configuration elements with translated versions of the same values. If the localized version uses a different image from the original, edit the value of the ImageUrl attribute to point to the alternative image. (If the image is not already deployed, you can deploy it in the project by adding a SharePoint "Image" Mapped Folder—which is mapped to the %ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\TEMPLATE\Images folder. Then add the image to that folder in the project.) Do not change the other attribute values in the file, such as ID.
9. Repeat the preceding steps for every language for which you want to provide a localized version of the site definition. Each time a new "XML" folder is created in the project, Visual Studio adds a number to the end of the folder name (XML 1, XML 2 ...). The numbers are for the convenience of you, the developer. The package manifest is automatically configured to deploy each file to the appropriate %ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LCID\XML folder.

Hope this can be of help.